# Simulate USB insertion on OSX via software

Tags: macos, usb, driver, iokit

How can I inject USB device nodes into OSX (>= 10.5) such as you might be able for debugging USB handlers / writing new USB drivers?

I'm interested in this in order to handle non-USB devices using TokenD.

From what it looks like, I would have to tackle faking USB-device insertion and then create a PC/SC ifdHandler that would handle this fake device.  (If anyone knows of any other way to inject a not-necessarily-device-backed TokenD, let me know!).

I'm guessing IOKit may be involved in this solution... as that is the underlying item I need to 'trick'.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I'm also interested in using a non-usb/smartcard device in a tokend.

Comment: I never did find a reasonable solution. It looks like the primary solution to this is to either:

 * create a static TokenD item, works if you have only 1 device to manage

 * Use IOKit and write a fake driver with hooks into userspace for control

Answer (score 1):

IOKit is pretty much the only thing involved, and you'll have to get a good grip on how it works before more specific answers will make any sense. If Apple's documentation doesn't do it for you, Amit Singh's book should pick up a lot of the slack, even if it is a little bit dated.